# How to separate two values from a sql cursor?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, mariadb

I have this database :

```
/* INSERT QUERY NO: 1 */
INSERT INTO table_name(city, lat, lng, sunrise)
VALUES
(
'Tokyo', 35.6897, 139.6922, ''
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 2 */
INSERT INTO table_name(city, lat, lng, sunrise)
VALUES
(
'Jakarta', -6.2146, 106.8451, ''
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 3 */
INSERT INTO table_name(city, lat, lng, sunrise)
VALUES
(
'Delhi', 28.66, 77.23, ''
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 4 */
INSERT INTO table_name(city, lat, lng, sunrise)
VALUES
(
'Mumbai', 18.9667, 72.8333, ''
);
```

how can i have lat and lng in diferrent strings?

I'm  query lat and lng and then assign both strings to this api and make a request to get the sunrise of the city using lat and lng :

https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400

and populate the database with each respective sunrise so i need the values separate. I'm using python not sure if i can request the values separate or maybe open two cursors? this is my  code so far:

Any sugestion advice to achive this will be awesome :)

```
import mysql.connector

mydb =mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",port=3306, user="avila",password="123289")

cursor = mydb.cursor()

cursor.execute("use test")

#cursor.execute("show tables")

sql = "select lat,lng from table_name"

cursor.execute(sql)

result = cursor.fetchone()


for x in result:
    print(x)

#for x in cursor:
    #print(x)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: You can copy and paste the output as plain text, not as image. And please describe, what is your issue? It shows you the latitude and longitude of the first (randomly) fetched row, this is what you need.

Comment: Hi! alredy edit sorry been overthinking, there's not actuall issue, i'm able to fetch the values but i need them in separate string, i think the question will be:  how can i have lat and lng in diferrent strings?

Comment: What do you mean? They are not strings at all (according to your insert statement), and what are "separate strings"? `fetchone`/`fetchmany` returns list of tuples

Comment: okay, i have to convert list of tupple to string?
what i mean i need  the latitud in one string and longitud in other string.